Root url is not working - Error: Token request failed
I am working on a react SPA using React Router in version 7.0.1. and got a problem with axa-fr/react-oidc (https://github.com/AxaFrance/oidc-client) and react router. To analyse the problem I created a new simple project where I had the same error.
I have created 3 routes with react router using createBrowserRouter.
main.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <App />,
        errorElement: (
            <App>
                <NotFoundPage />
            </App>
        ),
        children: [
            { path: "/", element: <MainPage /> },
            { path: "/main", element: <MainPage /> },
            { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
        ],
    },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
    <StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </StrictMode>
);

Here are the three components "App", "MainPage" and "About":
App.tsx
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function App(props: React.PropsWithChildren) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>App</h1>
            {props.children ? props.children : <Outlet />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

MainPage.tsx
const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>Main page</div>
            <Link to="/about">Go To About Page</Link>
        </>
    );
};

export default MainPage;

AboutPage.tsx
const About = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>About page</div>
            <Link to="/">Go To Main Page</Link>
        </>
    );
};

export default About;

This works fine. I can open all routes and the content is shown as expected.
Next I added react-oidc from (https://github.com/AxaFrance/oidc-client) for authentication with Microsoft using OIDC.
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <App />,
        errorElement: (
            <App>
                <NotFoundPage />
            </App>
        ),
        children: [
            { path: "/", element: <MainPage /> },
            { path: "/main", element: <MainPage /> },
            { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
        ],
    },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
    <StrictMode>
        <OidcProvider
            configuration={oidcConfig}
            onSessionLost={() => {
                console.log("Session lost !");
            }}
        >
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </OidcProvider>
    </StrictMode>
);

I added a Login Button on the AboutPage and visualize if I am authenticated an all pages.
After adding OIDC the root url (/) is reachable, but shows an authentication error from OIDC. The other routes (e. g. /main) are working as expected.
Error Message Root
Same problem if I am authenticated or not.
The other routes working as before.
// Console Log from Browser
@axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:626 
        
        
       POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/2cc9e43b-866e-4ab1-a168-d26afd434bcd/oauth2/v2.0/token 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:626
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:724
await in (anonymous)
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1408
await in (anonymous)
s @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1737
loginCallbackAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1740
Sn @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1597
loginCallbackWithAutoTokensRenewAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1757
loginCallbackAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1829
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1935
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1940
commitHookEffectListMount @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:16961
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18204
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18177
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18167
commitPassiveMountEffects @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18157
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19541
flushPassiveEffects @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19498
(anonymous) @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19379
workLoop @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:195
flushWork @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:382Understand this errorAI
hook.js:608 Error: Token request failed
    at @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1416:13
    at async s (@axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1737:17)
    at async Sn (@axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1597:48)
overrideMethod @ hook.js:608
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1455
await in (anonymous)
s @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1737
loginCallbackAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1740
Sn @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1597
loginCallbackWithAutoTokensRenewAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1757
loginCallbackAsync @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1829
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1935
(anonymous) @ @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1940
commitHookEffectListMount @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:16961
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18204
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18177
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18167
commitPassiveMountEffects @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:18157
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19541
flushPassiveEffects @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19498
(anonymous) @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:19379
workLoop @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:195
flushWork @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:174
performWorkUntilDeadline @ chunk-MVRAC76T.js?v=0f968381:382Understand this errorAI
hook.js:608 Error: Token request failed
    at @axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1416:13
    at async s (@axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1737:17)
    at async Sn (@axa-fr_react-oidc.js?v=0f968381:1597:48)

Hope someone can help that the root is working too.
